# Is there a way to convert google-class (objects) into Strings? (In Google App Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script

For Example, a common workflow that I use is :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
```

I call these 2 functions every time I want to read/write to my sheet. However, if there was a way to cache the result of
`SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)`, which returns a `Spreadsheet Object`, then I would assume to have increased performance, as it forgoes function calls. So far, both `PropertiesService` and `Cache` only support strings, hence the need for a conversion. Using `JSON.stringify` on spreadsheet or sheet doesn't seem to work... any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to cache this? Those calls take no time at all - is it even worth it?

Comment: If you're reading/writing to a sheet every time you call these methods then there isn't really anything you can do to speed this up. You would still need to propagate the changes you make to the sheet every time you make an edit and so the function calls will still have to be made. If you make this call at the beginning of the your function then there is really no need to cache this for speed's sake as the time to call is already very low and you can just reference the variables `spreadsheet` or `sheet` once the call has been made the first time.